# Ignore threads if the pool is full

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to achieve the following behaviour in my Java application:

When a button is clicked, a task is called in a new thread. However, if the button is clicked again and the current task is still running, I don't want to run another one.

I'm not sure what's a good approach to do this. Currently I'm using a code similar to the one below.

```
private ExecutorService backgroundTaskExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private boolean runningBackgroundTask = false;

private synchronized void setRunningBackgroundTask(boolean running) {
    this.runningBackgroundTask = running;
}

private synchronized boolean isRunningBackgroundTask() {
    return runningBackgroundTask;
}

private void runBackgroundTask() {

    if (isRunningBackgroundTask()) {
        System.out.println("This task will be ignored because the thread pool is busy.");
        return;
    }

    Runnable backgroundTask = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            setRunningBackgroundTask(true);
            // Do something that takes time...
            setRunningBackgroundTask(false);
        }
    };

    backgroundTaskExecutor.submit(backgroundTask);
}
```

Is this a good practice? Is there any utility in Java for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code you could end up with more than one task in the executor's queue at a time because you check if a task is running at the start of you method but only set it to true inside the runnable. It is completely possible that you could call the method twice before the first line of the runnable is run and the state is set to true.

To ensure this does not happen you could use an `AtomicBoolean` to get and set the state atomically.

```
private final AtomicBoolean runningBackgroundTask = new AtomicBoolean(false);

private void runBackgroundTask() {

    if (runningBackgroundTask.getAndSet(true)) {
        System.out.println("This task will be ignored because the thread pool is busy.");
        return;
    }

    Runnable backgroundTask = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do something that takes time...
            runningBackgroundTask.set(false);
        }
    };

    backgroundTaskExecutor.submit(backgroundTask);
}
```

Comment: Good solution, another one would be doing both the verification and starting the thread inside the same synchronized block.

Comment: Interesting, first time I hear about this. It seems safer than checking the flag in a synchronized method.

Comment: Your solution contains a data race:  The pool-thread could lose its time-slice after doing "something that takes time" but before setting the flag.  So there is a window of time in which a mouse-click is ignored even though nothing is happening at that moment.  It could create the illusion that the application is unstable (Sometimes, you click, and _nothing_ happens), or not.  It probably depends on how the completion of the task is synchronized with the display.  If the display has time to show the completion before a new click will be accepted, then you may have a problem.

Comment: @jameslarge The solution to that problem would be to not display that the task is completed before the flag is set. The program should behave as if the task completes at the same time as the flag is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution posted by Alex is fine, I'd like to provide an alternative that uses `Future`. It can be used when you want to run any (alien) `Runnable`, because it does not have to 'know' about the `runningBackgroundTask` flag:

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private Future<?> result;

private void runInBackground(Runnable task) {
    if (result != null && !result.isDone()) {
        // This task will be ignored because the thread pool is busy
        return;
    }

    result = executor.submit(task);
}
```

(Note that `result` is not synchronized, so this only works if `runInBackground` is always called by the same thread, which is true in your case as it is called by the button's event handler.)